# Powershell: Leave item alone if regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a list of pdf files (from daily processing), some with date stamps of various formatting, some without.

Example:

```
$f = @("testLtr06-09-02.pdf", "otherletter.pdf","WelcomeLtr043009.pdf")
```

I am trying to remove the datestamp by stripping out dashes, then replacing any consecutive group of numbers (4 or more, I may change this to 6) with the string "DATESTAMP".

So far I have this:

```
$d =  $f | foreach {$_ -replace "-", ""} | foreach { $_ -replace ([regex]::Matches($_ , "\d{4,}")), "DATESTAMP"}
echo $d
```

The output:

```
testLtrDATESTAMP.pdf
DATESTAMPoDATESTAMPtDATESTAMPhDATESTAMPeDATESTAMPrDATESTAMPlDATESTAMPeDATESTAMPtDATESTAMPtDATESTAMPeDATESTAMPrDATESTAMP.DATESTAMPpDATESTAMPdDATESTAMPfDATESTAMP
WelcomeLtrDATESTAMP.pdf
```

It works fine if the file has a datestamp but it seems to be freaking out the -replace and inserting DATESTAMP after every character. Is there a way to fix this? I tried to change it to a foreach loop but I couldn't figure out how to get true/false from regex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_ -replace ([regex]::Matches($_ , "\d{4,}")), "DATESTAMP"
```

Means in $_ replace every finding of `([regex]::Matches($_ , "\d{4,}"))` with `"DATESTAMP"`.

As in a filename with no timestamp (or at least 4 consecutive numbers) there is no match, it returns `""` (an empty string).

Thus every empty string gets replaced with `DATESTAMP`. And such a empty string `""` sits at the start of the string and after every other character.

Thats why you get this long string with every character surrounded by DATESTAMP.

---

To check if there even exists a `\d{4,}` in your string you should able to use

```
[regex]::IsMatch($_, "\d{4,}")
```

---

I'm no Powershell user but this line alone should do the job. But I'm not sure about being able to use the if in a pipeline and wether or not the assignment and the echo $d are needed

```
$f | foreach-object {$_ -replace "-", ""} | foreach-object {if ($_ -match "\d{4,}") { $_ -replace "\d{4,}", "DATESTAMP"} else { $_ }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that was what I was looking for in the loop version. Is there a way to do something akin to case or if clause in order to use IsMatch in the single statement without switching to a foreach ($item in $f)

Comment: You can also use the -match operator instead of [regex]::matches. Should be a little shorter and more readable.

Comment: Updated my answer to what I think should work. But be warned I'm no powershell user and the if-else statement in the pipeline might not be allowed.

Comment: You can do an if/else in a pipeline if it is part of a script block used by foreach-object.  I'll edit your pipeline to show the correct syntax.  By Shay Levy's answer really takes advantage of the regular expression support native in PowerShell.

Comment: That was basically what I was looking for. I was actually very close but I think I messed up the else { $_ } part. Wish I could accept two answers since Shay's is very nice as well.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do:

```
PS > $f -replace "(\d{2}-){2}\d{2}|\d{4,}","DATESTAMP"
testLtrDATESTAMP.pdf
otherletter.pdf
WelcomeLtrDATESTAMP.pdf
```

Comment: This works perfectly as well. I need to brush up on my Regex to make some sense out of it, however :)

Thanks! I'll bump this as soon as I get the required rep points.